# Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. http to https redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have this error in a woocommerce website:

Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.

I supposed i have an error in my redirection in .htaccess but i didnt found it. any idea?

I have this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://tattootatu.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE] 

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /en/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /en/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

AddType image/svg+xml .svg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml

################ Expires Control ################
ExpiresByType image/svg+xml "access 1 month"


# TN - BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
<filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "private"
</filesMatch>
<filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# TN - END Cache-Control Headers

# TN - BEGIN Turn ETags Off
FileETag None
# TN - END Turn ETags Off
```

Thanks in advance,
David

Comment: I think it is something related to rewritebase, try to remove /en from rewrite rule.

Comment: Thanks you are right.

Comment: Then i note that wordpress was change automatically my .htaccess. I change permisions to 444 and problem solve.